# OpenGLRenderer: Davey

Tags: android

I have noticed that from time to time, android shows the following log message:

```
I/OpenGLRenderer( 4958): Davey! duration=1923ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=12247...
```

Does anyone know the reason why my OpenGLRenderer is calling `Davey!`?

Comment: Your application is skipping frames. That's just a check I think.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

This "Davey!" is here because Dave Burke, VP on Android, cares deeply about jank and performance and filed many, many, many bugs for the engineering teams. This is just a fun nod to him when the system automatically detects jank.

Comment: I think you are going to have to get Dave Burke to write a blog and confirm this :-) Looks like this version of the truth needs more upvotes.

Comment: Ok, I see that this would also make a lot of sense :D @Frank I think we should really do this to confirm it :)

Comment: I'm just here to say I absolutely enjoy this kind of tomfoolery.

Comment: @Frank leaving this here for you: https://youtu.be/wppe_zKsLlA?t=39487

Comment: @Napoli Holy crap no way!! That's incredible. Nice one, Napoli. Thanks for that.I love these easter egg like oddities.

Comment: This is what being a dev is all about :D

Comment: Does this count as a blog post? https://twitter.com/davey_burke/status/1404968531469357058

Comment: @ArtemRussakovskii He actually replied! I think we can call this confirmed ;D

Comment: @Romain Guy anyway to disable these logs ?  I guess we can do this since they are in the android source code

Comment: This reminds me of the blimp strat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UF4QGYW25oI

Answer (score 32):

I had the same question. It looks like a name, but the code suggests it isn't (?).
From Android source file frameworks/base/libs/hwui/JankTracker.cpp, around line 177

```cpp
....
    // Log daveys since they are weird and we don't know what they are (b/70339576)
    if (totalDuration >= 700_ms) {
        static int sDaveyCount = 0;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "Davey! duration=" << ns2ms(totalDuration) << "ms; ";
....
```

The logging code was added here: [Android 0e89ca2088b7e5424b35d9a564b83847dc0df84a](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e89ca2088b7e5424b35d9a564b83847dc0df84a). 
Maybe ask the engineer that added the code: [John Reck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133252/john-reck) .

Answer (score 7):

"Davey" is a transliteration of the Russian "Дава́й"

It means "come on!" and is an expression used to mean anything from "GO!" (in the sense of 'watch out!') to "COME ON!!!" (in the sense of 'hurry up! go!')

The programmer adding this was probably not Russian but making some kind of Slavic language joke.

Comment: Lol, that would actually make sense because it logs if some duration is longer than 700ms, so it writes "Hurry up! duration was x". Thanks for the interesting info

Comment: Not quite, see my top level answer :)

Comment: Yeah this is definitely wrong but it was a good guess :-D

Comment: I do believe @RomainGuy is correct : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/345305/xamarin-forms-what-does-this-mean-(openglrenderer)